# Signature authority for corporations?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, california, corporate-law

Let's say I'm a disgruntled McDonald's employee. One day I walk up to someone and give them a piece of paper saying "McDonald's agrees to give you ONE MILLYUN DOLLARS in exchange for your pocket change. Signed, me, on behalf of McDonald's."

Now, I really doubt that this contract could be enforced against McDonald's in court. Presumably their articles of incorporation specifically set a list of people with the authority to enter into contracts like this, and presumably that list included only high-level directors and such. Yet clearly other people in the organisation have some authority to enter into contracts, for purposes ranging from signing payroll checks to buying supplies.

So how is all this regulated? What determines what agreements a given employee can enter into on behalf of their company, particularly if there aren't any specific provisions in that person's employment contract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Australia a person must have ostensible authority as an agent (agency by estoppel) to bind their corporation.

If a person claims the authority and a reasonable person would believe in the circumstances that they have the authority then their actions bind the company. See http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/ca2001172/s769b.html for the law and http://www.mondaq.com/australia/x/386390/Contract+Law/Companies+and+perils+of+ostensible+authority+the+danger+of+paying+money+to+a+third+party+and+not+to+the+creditor for a case.

To take your example (and putting aside the fact that the purported contract is probably unenforceable in itself), if a reasonable person would conclude you had the authority (in your capacity as director or senior executive) then it would bind McDonalds; if you were a store manager or burger flipper, it wouldn't.

Comment: This sounds a little scary/surprising: entities can be bound merely by "ostensible authority?"  Can you provide any references?  Because I might know a guy in a non-extraditing country who is ready to visit Australia, dress up in a suit, print some business cards, and sign a bunch of lucrative contracts on behalf of deep-pocketed entities for the extraordinary benefit of third parties that happen to be publicly traded.

Comment: [Per Hodgson JA](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/cases/nsw/NSWCA/2004/375.html) _"Ostensible authority occurs where the principal, by words or conduct, represents that the agent has the requisite actual authority, and the party dealing with the agent enters into a contract in reliance on that representation"_. That is, the _principal_ must represent that the agent has authority, and not merely the agent on their own. [Here](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/cases/nsw/NSWSC/2013/646.html)'s another case where actions of an ostensible agent does not amount to authority.

Comment: That is, it appears that a positive act or holding out by the principal is required to delegate ostensible authority to the supposed agent for the company.

Comment: @feetwet and would the beneficiaries of these "contracts" have reasonably believed he had the authority?

Comment: @Dale M great answer. You are totally  right... If it was a person who had authority, then it could potentially, in the abstract, be binding. Smaller Corporations usually have a few key players (CLO,CEO, COO) who can contact on behalf of the corporate entity with autonomy. That is less so with publicly traded corps or very valuable closely held ones... In those instances a quorum vote if the board is necessary. The articles of incorporation lay out who has this authority and there are legal requisites for publicly traded entities

Comment: @DaleM I don't think that matters. It's not enough for me to be convincing. The principal must also act in a way that represents that the agent has the authority to enter into the contract.

Comment: @gracey209 I have to disagree. This answer is effectively saying (unless I'm grossly misreading it) that "if it looks good enough, it is". The case law says otherwise.

Comment: @jimsug sometimes the principal gives blanket authority. In a case like this, it would be as simple as the corporation filing an action stating its agent exceeded his authority, and it would be clear there was no consideration gained between the corp and the "buyer", only between that and agent... A return of the pocket change and the deal would be invalidated. Most times there are blanket amounts for which authority is no longer valid. For instance, X can enter into agreements without any formal checks and balances under 100k.

Comment: So from what I gather: the Principal must either represent that the Agent has ostensible authority, or hold out with the knowledge that the third party is relying on this. However, I don't think whether the parties to the contracts in @feetwet's comment believed he had the authority matters - that person has no authority, ostensible or otherwise. A non-agent cannot bind a company.

Comment: Who *is* the principal in the case of a company? A company is not physically capable of directly doing anything; anything it "does" is done by a human on its behalf.

Comment: @cpast, typically the CEO will be the principal, or other's just under or appointed, but nobody could sell a corporation like this...even if it was the actual CEO doing it.

Comment: It returns to what is reasonable. It is incumbent to some extent on the other party to satisfy themselves that the person has the authority. If you are buying groceries the person on the checkout probably has the authority, if you are buying the property they probably don't.